# How do I describe a disk that rotates on a rotating tripod?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

I have a question about the following experimental setup:

A cylinder stands upright on a table. This cylinder rotates around its axis. On top of this cylinder, a wooden disc about 3 cm thick is placed in the center. The cylinder has a diameter of 5cm and the disk a diameter of 20cm.

I would like to know how heavy a weight I have to place on the edge of the disk so that it falls off the rotating cylinder. The weight can be a small metal block or something similar. Of course, you need more measured values in the end. This should only be a qualitative description of my problem.

If one would put a rod on the cylinder instead of the disk and the cylinder would not move, then I could probably derive the necessary relations simply with the lever law (torque). But I am not sure if I can do the same here or if I have to consider more. Especially since the cylinder has a finite extension, so it is not simply a pivot point. Does anyone have an idea what I have to consider?

Comment: If it’s an “experimental setup”, why aren’t you determining the weight experimentally?

Comment: Because I want to determine the weight theoretically and than test if my theory matches with the real result.